# NGINX error: "Invalid port in upstream" when using proxy_pass with IPv6

Tags: nginx

I have been unable to find an explanation for this NGINX error on nginx version: nginx/1.9.14.

This nginx.conf attempts to forward a client request to from webserver port 442 to port 9442.

When using an IPv4 client and server address everything works fine and the webserver request is forwarded to 9442.  When using an IPv6 address client and server address the following error occurs:

```
2017/08/21 19:05:56 [error] 6694#0: *5 invalid port in upstream "2000::157:9442/", client: 2000::158, server: , request: "GET / HTTP/1.1",   host: "[2000::157]:442"
```

nginx.conf:

```
http {
    server {
        listen       442 ssl; # IPv4 support
        listen       [::]:442 ssl; # IPv6 support

        ssl_certificate      /etc/ssl/active.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key  /etc/ssl/active.key;

        ssl on;
        ssl_session_cache builtin:1000 shared:SSL:10m;
        ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

        location / {
            proxy_pass https://$server_addr:9442$request_uri;
        }
    }
}
```

What does "invalid port in upstream" mean exactly?

Note that the IPv6 addresses in this example are made up for the sake of this example and are on a private network not seen by the outside world.

Comment: Try this `listen       [::]:442 ssl ipv6only=on; # IPv6 support`

Comment: Why you want to use $server_address instead of localhost?

Comment: @TarunLalwani I tried ipv6only=on and have the same result. Also I think its defaulted to on in my version anyways from looking at documentation.

Comment: @AlexeyTen localhost gets the following error: 2017/08/22 18:47:42 [error] 32549#0: *276 no resolver defined to resolve localhost, client: 2000::158, server: , request: "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1", host: "[2000::157]:442"

Comment: @Chadness3, i know why the issue happening just need to test how to fix it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So the issue is because of the IP formats. `$sever_addr` will get `127.0.0.1` or any local ip for IPv4. While for IPv6 it would get `::1` or `2000::157` like the one you got. Or something which will have `:` in the address.

Now when you `proxy_pass` using `$server_addr`, it become either `http://127.0.0.1:9442` or `http://::1:9442`. IPv4 one is valid but the IPv6 one is not valid. It needs to be `http://[::1]:9442`. The fix is easy, we use a map in our http block.

```
map $server_addr $proxy_pass_ip {
    default "$server_addr";
    ~.*:.*   "[$server_addr]";
}
```

And we change our location block like

```
location / {
   proxy_pass https://$proxy_pass_ip:9442$request_uri;
}
```

Comment: Nice, yes I just figured that out as well. I actually made two server {} blocks - one for ipv4 and one for ipv6, but your solution is much better. I will try out your fix.

Comment: This works OK for IPv4 but IPv6 gets the following error, seems like the address isn't being substituted into $proxy_pass_ip: 2017/08/22 20:40:03 [error] 11200#0: *14 invalid IPv6 address in upstream "[$server_addr]:9442/json-rpc/11.0/", client: 2000::158, server: , reqest: "POST /json-rpc/11.0/ HTTP/1.1", host: "[2000::157]:442", referrer: "https://[2000::157]:442/config/"

Comment: Which version of nginx? Because I had tested on the latest one and it had worked fine

Comment: Version is 1.9.4

Comment: Latest is 1.13.4 so please try the latest one

Answer (score 0):

The issue, that Tarun pointed out correctly, is that []'s are needed for the IPv6 address that is forwarded to https::

One solution to this problem is to create two server blocks. I'd like to use @TarunLalwani's solution but so far I haven't been able to get it to work:

```
http {
    server {
        listen       442 ssl; # IPv4 support

        ssl_certificate      /etc/ssl/active.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key  /etc/ssl/active.key;

        ssl on;
        ssl_session_cache builtin:1000 shared:SSL:10m;
        ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

        location / {
            proxy_pass https://$server_addr:9442$request_uri;
        }
    }
    server {
        listen       [::]:442 ssl; # IPv6 support

        ssl_certificate      /etc/ssl/active.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key  /etc/ssl/active.key;

        ssl on;
        ssl_session_cache builtin:1000 shared:SSL:10m;
        ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

        location / {
            proxy_pass https://[$server_addr:9442]$request_uri;
        }
    }
}
```